# Unity3D-2D: Setting Time.timeScale to 0 for a certain public prefab until positioned?

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So I have a button in my game which spawns a "tower" at a given location. The tower, when spawned, acts normally and I can drag it around using my drag script.

I wonder how can I set the Time.timeScale to 0 when I first spawn the tower (*only* for that prefab) UNTILL I click again to set it's position.

Also after the click on the button I want to enable my dragging script, set the position and after another click with the mouse to disable the dragging script. That way I can make sure players don't reposition towers for extra damage.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnTower : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject FrozenObject;
    public Transform prefab;
    public void OnClickSpawn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(i * 2.0F, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

    //this part from here on DOES NOT WORK! It says that the GetComponent<>() method that is not valin in the given context
    public void OnClick()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            GetComponent<DragEnemy>.enabled = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Note the part that doesn't work

And this is my dragging script which for some reason can't be referenced to be disabled.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]

public class DragEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {

        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = curPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth posting this in the Game Development community? A lot of Unity questions can be seen there: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thanks mate. I didn't know there was a gamedev section of this website. Cheers